# Time Difference returns NULL

Tags: mysql, time

I am trying to get the time for a contract to run out from my database. I now have this query, but I cannot seem to figure out why I get NULL for the to_expire field. The query runs fine, and produces the expected results except for the calculated timediff. cs_start and cs_end are date fields

```
  SELECT cs_start, cs_end, cs_status, 
 TIMEDIFF(date(now()),  cs_start) as to_expire,
 GROUP_CONCAT(is_name SEPARATOR '<br /> ') as partners 
  FROM `contracttoinstitute` 
  JOIN `institutes`
    ON is_id = ctt_institute_id
  JOIN `contracts` 
    on ctt_contract_id  = cs_id
 WHERE ctt_contract_id 
    IN (
      select ctt_contract_id 
        from `contracttoinstitute`
       where ctt_institute_id = 1 
       )
   AND ctt_institute_id <> 1 
  GROUP BY ctt_contract_id
  ORDER BY cs_id DESC
```

Output:

```
 cs_start cs_end cs_status to_expire partners 
2013-11-06  2014-01-01  signed  NULL    KATHOLIEKE HOG   
...
```

As was hoping to get some value. Not sure what timediff SHOULD give; First time I try to use it. (I am looking for a value to sort by, in order to determine whether a contract is about to lapse)

Comment: Can you show example data and expected output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `datediff()`.  You are exceeding the range of `timediff()` and seem to want days anyway:

```
  SELECT cs_start, cs_end, cs_status, 
         datediff(date(now()),  cs_start) as to_expire,
         GROUP_CONCAT(is_name SEPARATOR '<br /> ') as partners
```

Comment: Simple. Works. Should have known a datediff existed. Sigh, sometimes I can kick myself..